# session_unset() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php

Hola todos tengo un pequeño problema, cuando trato de hacer logeo en mi pag del proyecto de la uni me sale este error y no encuentro como solucionarlo, se trata de un blog, dejare la imagen abajo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca dejare el codigo para que me ayuden si encuentran el fallo, como no tengo mucha exp no se que puede estar mal

```
<?php

//iniciar la sesion y la conexion a db 
require_once 'includes/conexion.php';

//recoger datos del formularios
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Borrar error antiguo
    if (isset($_SESSION['error_login'])) {
        # code...
        session_unset($_SESSION['error_login']);
    }

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //comprobar las credenciales del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $login =mysqli_query($daba, $sql);

    if ($login && mysqli_query_num_rows($login) ==1) {
        # code...
        $usuario =mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);

    }
    //comprobar password / cifrar
    $verify = password_verify($password, $usuario['password']);

    if ($verify) {
        //utilizar una sesion para guardar los datos del usuario
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;


    }else {
        //si algo falla enviar una sesion con el fallo
        $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrecto";
    }

}else {
    # code...
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrecto";
}

//redirigir al index.php
header('Location: Index.php');
```

Comment: Bueno uno de los errores te indica que le pasaste un argumento a la función `session_unset` y que de hecho no espera ninguno es decir que no requiere argumentos

Comment: Ojo. El comentario de @BetaM es correcto. Pero no tiene en cuenta que lo que deseas en ese momento es anular el registro de error. Debes cambiar `session_unset($_SESSION['error_login'])` por `unset($_SESSION['error_login'])` para eliminar esa clave particular del registro de sesión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PARTE 1**

Tu segundo error es que tratas de usar a la función **`mysqli_query_num_rows()`** pero la misma no existe.

En cambio deberás usar:

- Consulta
- Verificación del valor numérico que devuelve la variable que contiene la consulta

Código:

```
$consulta =mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM ................");
$valorNumerico = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

Por otro lado esta comparación: **`$login && mysqli_query_num_rows($login) ==1`** pues lo ideal sería comparar cada variable por separado contra el valor en cuestión

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' ";

$login =mysqli_query($daba, $sql);
$ejecucion = mysqli_num_rows($login);

    if ($ejecucion==1) 
    {
        $usuario =mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);
    }
```

**PARTE 2**

A diferencia de [**`session_unset()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-unset.php) que es de caracter **`void`** y no espera el paso de argumentos puedes usar a la función [**`unset()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) que si se le puede pasar variables específicas a destruir su valor asociado

```
unset($_SESSION['error_login']);
```

- session__unset() -> Libera todas las variables
- unset() -> Libera la variable pasada como argumento

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo bien que queres hacer con la **`$_SESSION`**, proba destruyéndola con un **`session_destroy()`**

Estás escribiendo

```
mysqli_query_num_rows($login)
```

y es

```
mysqli_num_rows($login)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

session_unset($_SESSION['error_login']);

Hola, probá colocando ---> session_unset();

Como dijeron BetaM y quevedo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar esto

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error_login'])) {
    # code...
    session_unset($_SESSION['error_login']);
}
```

por esto :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error_login'])) {
    # code...
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = null;
    session_unset();
}
```

session_unset() lo que hace es que libera todas las variables tipo sesión y según la documentación, no hay necesidad de especificar las variable tipo sesión a liberar.  Para más información te dejo este link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de lo que hace tu código y si es posible enlaces de documentación, considera que los usuarios nuevos con poca experiencia no entenderán tu respuesta, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtener tu primera medalla. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, editaré mi respuesta para poder explicar por qué lo hice así.